# Multivariable Regression: does "no exact multicolinearity between variables" mean the same as saying that the X's are independent of one another

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm looking at some notes on multivariable regression. It states that one of the assumptions for Least Squares to give good estimates is that,

"There is no exact linear relationship between any of the variables (no exact multicolinearity)".

Would this be the same as saying that the explanatory variables are all independent of one another.

On a related note, does the word "exact" in the statement above refer to perfect correlation between two variables. What if the correlation was strong but not perfect, would OLS still give good estimates?

Comment: No: Let X be uniform [-1,1]  Let Y be two valued with P(Y=-1)=P(Y=1)= 1/2.  Let Z=XY.  X and Z are uncorrelated, but they are certainly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

"No multicollinearity" means that no variable is a linear combination of the other variables, i.e. $x_1 = 2 x_2 - 4 x_3 + x_4$ is not allowed. This is equivalent to saying that the design matrix $X$ (where each row corresponds to a data point and each column corresponds to a variable) has *linearly independent* columns.

Note that there is no notion of randomness in this definition. You do not need a probabilistic model to talk about multicollinearity; it is a statement about the actual data that you have (the design matrix $X$).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I understand what you mean. So in the example you've cited would the correlation coefficient between $x_1$ and $2x_2-4x_3+x_4$ be equal to 1?

Comment: One final question, if some variables are colinear does that mean it would not be possible to calculate all/some of the regression coefficients?

Comment: @NumberCruncher Yes that correlation would be $1$. Collinearity would mean there is no unique least squares coefficient (actually there will be infinitely many settings of coefficients that minimize the least squares criterion). In terms of the $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y$ formula for computing the least squares coefficient, the fact that $X$ has linearly dependent columns makes $X^\top X$ not invertible.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you very much for the answers.